# Filtering array strings with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

How could I write a numpy function where it only filters out the array strings that ends with 'USD'. How would I be able to execute this filter without a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
Array= ['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'David', 'georGe', 'XRPUSD', 'USDAUD', 'ETHUSDC' ]
```

Expected Output

```
['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD',  'XRPUSD']
```

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have fast string methods, so beware of trying to replace list/string methods with `numpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy [char.endswith](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.endswith.html#numpy-char-endswith)

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'David', 'georGe', 'XRPUSD', 'USDAUD', 'ETHUSDC'])
print(a[np.char.endswith(a, 'USD')])
```

Output:

```
['BTCUSD' 'ETHUSD' 'XRPUSD']
```

---

For a return type of `list` instead of `np.ndarray` a comprehension can be used:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array(['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'David', 'georGe', 'XRPUSD', 'USDAUD', 'ETHUSDC'])
print([elem for elem in lst if elem.endswith('USD')])
```

Output:

```
['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'XRPUSD']
```

*The comprehension approach can be used on Python lists as well as np arrays.

Comment: My experience is that `np.char` functions have about the same speed as list comprehensions.  They still use python string methods.

Comment: I tried doing `a[np.char.endswith(a, 'USD', 'USDT')]` however doesnt really work