# Filtering Multi Array Strings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, filter

I want to write a numpy funcction that filters the `a` array to only the ones that end with `USD` and `USDC`. The function below only works with one filter but does not work with two filters `'USD', 'USDC'`. Code has been gotten from issue:[issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305929/filtering-array-strings-with-numpy)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'David', 'georGe', 'XRPUSD', 'USDAUD', 'ETHUSDC'])
print(a[np.char.endswith(a, 'USD', 'USDC')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'David', 'georGe', 'XRPUSD', 'USDAUD', 'ETHUSDC'])
b = np.array([i for i in a if i.endswith('USDC') or i.endswith('USD')])
print(b)
```